IAsyncEnumerable + OpenAI only stream on localhost
I have a controller
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<ActionResult<Answer>> SendQuestionAsync([FromBody] Question question)
{
    await foreach (var item in _mediator.CreateStream(command))
    {               
        yield return new Answer()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            DateTime = item.DateTime,
            Message = item.Message,
        };
    }
}

With MediatR I invoke the following handler (some class content ignored):
public class ChatCommandHandler : IStreamRequestHandler<Question, Answer> 
{
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<Answer> Handle(Question command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    {
        var completions = ...

        await foreach (var update in await openAIClient.GetChatCompletionsStreamingAsync(completions)) 
        {
            yield return new Answer()
            {
                Message = update.ContentUpdate,
            };
        }
    }
}

It works fine on localhost, I received many chunks from Azure OpenAI, but when I executed the same code on a Azure Web App I only receive the first chunk, and then the rest of chunks at once
What's wrong? is really weird for me
The issue is like this IAsyncEnumerable not streaming response when connected with Azure OpenAI ChatCompletionsStreamingAsync
Note that I'm using NET 8

Try this HttpContext.Features.Get().DisableBuffering();.
